# Variable instantiated in prepare for Segue has nil properties in ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, core-location

My view controller is loading before Core Location data is available from the model.

I've a Master View controller that modally pushes a new view controller with two `NSManagedObject` subclasses - records and locations - which are instantiated in a `prepareForSegue` method.

```
if segue.identifier == "newRecord"
    {
        let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! NewRecordVC)

        let appDelegate    = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate     // instantiate the delegate methods in AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate!.managedObjectContext      // create context from delegate methods

        let recordEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("RecordData", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
        let locationEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Location", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        controller.location = Location(entity: locationEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
        controller.record = Record(entity: recordEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
        controller.managedContext = appDelegate?.managedObjectContext
        print("segueing")
    }
```

Both managed objects have `inits` for various values. Records have simple pre-assigned values assigned to properties that show up on the new view. Location properties, however, mainly require location services to assign property values. Printing property values shows that while a location is instantiated in `viewDidLoad`, the location properties assigned by location services are still nil. Location services are working - the properties print from within the model, BUT this is after `viewDidLoad`. On load, I need at least the `geoPlacemark` property, which provides text for the view.

```
    override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    if let recordNotNil = record
    {
        ...
        iD.text = "ID: \(recordNotNil.iD)"
    }

    if let locationNotNil = location
    {
        ...
        print("bing")
        print(locationNotNil.temp)
        record!.location = location!
        print(location.geoPlacemark)
        print(location.timestamp)
        if let geoPlacemarkNotNil = location.geoPlacemark
        {
            print("bong")
            locationText(geoPlacemarkNotNil)
        }
    }
}
```

Do I have to run the location services from within every view controller, not the model? Or is there a way to get the view to wait for the location delegate methods?

Comment: As you pass the managed object context anyway, it might be easier to create the CoreData objects in the destination view controller in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I tried this, but the sequence of events remains: Segue to VC; viewDidLoad with basic property values assigned, but no Core Location property values assigned (nil); an alert to allow location services; then I get data from didUpdateLocations, including the placemark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here came from using the normal override init method for the NSManagedObject.

```
class Record: NSManagedObject
{
override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?)
{
    super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    let randomBit = String(arc4random_uniform(100))
    iD = NSDate().toIDTimeDateString() + "-" + randomBit + "OtR"

    believers = 0
    deviceTime = NSDate()
    doubters = 0
    eventTimeStarted = NSDate()
    eventTimeEnded = NSDate()
    featureImageIndex = 0
    coreLocationUsed = 0
    photoTaken = 0
    tableSection = "My Records"
    timeRecorded = deviceTime
    validationScore = 0
}
}
```

As per the [apple doc.s](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/LifeofaManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH16-SW1), custom NSManagedObjects should be initiated using awakeFromInsert or awakeFromFetch.

Answer (score 0):

In `prepareForSegue()` the destinationViewController is already instantiated, and `viewDidLoad()` was already called.
If you want to set a label you should really do it in `viewWillAppear()`

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()

    // Set up your views here
}
```

The other benefit of `viewWillAppear()` over `viewDidLoad()` is that it's called every time the ViewController is about to show up, which can be multiple times during the VCs lifecycle - as opposed to a single call ad the beginning of the VC's lifecycle of `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to change it at all. The sequence of events remains: Segue to VC; viewWillAppear with basic properties, but no location services data (nil); didUpdateLocations; and finally the geoPlacemark.

Comment: Can you check in the debugger if you successfully create the location and record objects in `prepareForSegue`
?

Comment: The records are instantiated - these property values appear on the view. I do optional chaining on the location property, and can print to console (even simple property values, just not location values).

Comment: I'm note sure I understand. Are you saying that in `prepareForSegue`you successfully instantiate the Record object but the Location objects fails to instantiate? Or did I get this wrong?

Comment: Both seem to instantiate. I can print non-location property values (eg, arbitrary string value) from both in the viewWillLoad or viewDidLoad, but I cannot print any core location derived property values. I can only print these values from within the location delegate methods.

Comment: There's not a single reference to CoreLocation in your code, only to NSManagedObjects which happen to be named `Location`. Maybe you edit the question or better ask another one if you got problems with CoreLocation. This one was about passing values in `prepareForSegue`and I think it has been answered.